# Pandas using groupby on a groupby object

Tags: python, pandas

I have a timeseries dataframe with Date, Symbol and some values with granularity of 1 min data.
I want to resample it to 5 min bucket. Each symbol has to grouped separately. I have attached sample data in the end, use `pd.from_dict()` to get data in dataframe. `Symbol` is meant to represent stock market tickers (more specifically options on the same ticker). Real data may contain hundreds of Symbols

Resampling a single symbol is easy

```
df = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='Date',freq='5Min')).agg({'Open': 'first', 
                                 'High': 'max', 
                                 'Low': 'min', 
                                 'Close': 'last',}).reset_index()
```

But doing it for multiple symbols is not so straightforward. What I am thinking of is that first I group them by `Symbol` and then group them again with `Date` but I have no idea how this would work because you can't chain groupby

pseudo code would be something like

`df.groupby('Symbol').groupby(pd.Grouper(key='Date',freq='5Min')).agg...`

```
{'Date': {0: '2018-01-01 09:15:00',
  1: '2018-01-01 09:16:00',
  2: '2018-01-01 09:17:00',
  3: '2018-01-01 09:18:00',
  4: '2018-01-01 09:19:00',
  5: '2018-01-01 09:20:00',
  6: '2018-01-01 09:21:00',
  7: '2018-01-01 09:22:00',
  8: '2018-01-01 09:23:00',
  9: '2018-01-01 09:24:00',
  10: '2018-01-01 09:25:00',
  11: '2018-01-01 09:15:00',
  12: '2018-01-01 09:16:00',
  13: '2018-01-01 09:17:00',
  14: '2018-01-01 09:18:00',
  15: '2018-01-01 09:19:00',
  16: '2018-01-01 09:20:00',
  17: '2018-01-01 09:21:00',
  18: '2018-01-01 09:22:00',
  19: '2018-01-01 09:23:00',
  20: '2018-01-01 09:24:00',
  21: '2018-01-01 09:25:00'},
 'Open': {0: 10531.7,
  1: 10523.0,
  2: 10525.8,
  3: 10522.6,
  4: 10521.05,
  5: 10524.2,
  6: 10526.85,
  7: 10529.95,
  8: 10533.2,
  9: 10530.95,
  10: 11528.4,
  11: 11531.7,
  12: 11523.0,
  13: 11525.8,
  14: 11522.6,
  15: 11521.05,
  16: 11524.2,
  17: 11526.85,
  18: 11529.95,
  19: 11533.2,
  20: 11530.95,
  21: 11528.4},
 'High': {0: 10533.7,
  1: 10527.5,
  2: 10526.15,
  3: 10522.95,
  4: 10523.8,
  5: 10530.25,
  6: 10530.3,
  7: 10533.55,
  8: 10534.8,
  9: 10531.25,
  10: 11529.1,
  11: 11533.7,
  12: 11527.5,
  13: 11526.15,
  14: 11522.95,
  15: 11523.8,
  16: 11530.25,
  17: 11530.3,
  18: 11533.55,
  19: 11534.8,
  20: 11531.25,
  21: 11529.1},
 'Low': {0: 10518.35,
  1: 10522.25,
  2: 10522.6,
  3: 10519.65,
  4: 10520.9,
  5: 10523.65,
  6: 10526.8,
  7: 10529.95,
  8: 10530.1,
  9: 10527.6,
  10: 11526.1,
  11: 11518.35,
  12: 11522.25,
  13: 11522.6,
  14: 11519.65,
  15: 11520.9,
  16: 11523.65,
  17: 11526.8,
  18: 11529.95,
  19: 11530.1,
  20: 11527.6,
  21: 11526.1},
 'Close': {0: 10523.15,
  1: 10525.95,
  2: 10522.6,
  3: 10521.35,
  4: 10523.7,
  5: 10526.45,
  6: 10530.3,
  7: 10533.3,
  8: 10530.5,
  9: 10528.45,
  10: 11527.45,
  11: 11523.15,
  12: 11525.95,
  13: 11522.6,
  14: 11521.35,
  15: 11523.7,
  16: 11526.45,
  17: 11530.3,
  18: 11533.3,
  19: 11530.5,
  20: 11528.45,
  21: 11527.45},
 'Symbol': {0: 'A',
  1: 'A',
  2: 'A',
  3: 'A',
  4: 'A',
  5: 'A',
  6: 'A',
  7: 'A',
  8: 'A',
  9: 'A',
  10: 'B',
  11: 'B',
  12: 'B',
  13: 'B',
  14: 'B',
  15: 'B',
  16: 'B',
  17: 'B',
  18: 'B',
  19: 'B',
  20: 'B',
  21: 'B'}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can use a list of grouper:

```
out = (df.groupby(['Symbol', pd.Grouper(key='Date', freq='5Min')], as_index=False)
         .agg({'Open': 'first', 'High': 'max', 'Low': 'min', 'Close': 'last'}))
```

Output:

```
>>> out
  Symbol                Date     Open     High       Low     Close
0      A 2018-01-01 09:15:00  10531.7  10533.7  10518.35  10523.70
1      A 2018-01-01 09:20:00  10524.2  10534.8  10523.65  10528.45
2      B 2018-01-01 09:15:00  11531.7  11533.7  11518.35  11523.70
3      B 2018-01-01 09:20:00  11524.2  11534.8  11523.65  11528.45
4      B 2018-01-01 09:25:00  11528.4  11529.1  11526.10  11527.45
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this approach:
First, you **group** the data by **Symbol** and then you group each symbol's data by the **5-minute interval**. Data is the dictionary which hash a list for each column name like date, open, high. Just like the one you attached.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
# Group by and then resample each group with 5-minute intervals
df_resampled = df.groupby('Symbol').resample('5T', on='Date').agg({
    'Open': 'first',
    'High': 'max',
    'Low': 'min',
    'Close': 'last'
}).reset_index()
```

Check documentation:
[Pandas Resample](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html)

Comment: Your code worked perfectly but the performance of the selected answer was much better. Just to put the stats for everyone, on my sample looping 100 times, @Corralien code took 5.77 ms per loop whereas your code took 22.9 ms. On full scale of data, this savings is enormous